How do I transform "48a493d902b5" into "48:a4:93:d9:02:b5" in Java?
I have a string "48a493d902b5", but I need to convert it in "48:a4:93:d9:02:b5". I could build a While structure but i don't know if it is the better aproach.
Is it possible use Regex for it? If so, How can I do it?

Yes, it's possible use a regex. This expression (.{2}) splits the String in pairs of characters using the lookBehind (?<=\G.{2}) and in the sequence inserts ":" between this pairs, except for the last pair (?!$).
    String originalString = "48a493d902b5";
    String formatedString = originalString.replaceAll("(?<=\\G.{2})(?!$)", ":");
    System.out.println(formatedString);


alternative: replaceAll("(..)(?=.)", "$1:")

I liked this aproach, but something are missing. The result was "48:a493d902b5"

The alternative works fine. Thank you

One approach would be to use the StringBuilder class. I guess that you want to have several Strings that would be transformed to the format that includes ':'. An example of such a function would be:
public String convertToFormat(String input) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i % 2 == 0) {
      sb.append(":");
    }
    sb.append(input.charAt(i));
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

String firstVersion = "48a493d902b5";
String newVersion = convertToFormat(firstVersion);
System.out.println(newVersion);


You could also step by 2, and use StringBuilder.append(CharSequence,int,int) to append two-char subsequences.

You might also want to consider the following:

(..) capture all instances of 2 digits and with a back reference followed by a colon.
(?!$) - ignore end of string pairings.

String s = "48a493d902b5";
String  s1 = s.replaceAll("(..)(?!$)","$1:");
System.out.println(s1);

prints
48:a4:93:d9:02:b5

For similar constructs you may want to check out HexFormat
For example, you can specify a delimiter and change the case.  Here using a BigInteger to convert the hex String to a byte array.
String s = "48a493d902b5a792f3FF821234aabc3123";
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(s, 16);
String result = HexFormat.ofDelimiter(":").withUpperCase()
        .formatHex(bigInt.toByteArray());
System.out.println(result);

prints
48:A4:93:D9:02:B5:A7:92:F3:FF:82:12:34:AA:BC:31:23



